# For dynamically customized forms, how can python scripts implement auto-selection?

Tags: javascript, python, html, scripting, auto

I would like to implement this form auto-selection in python language, but for the options of the drop-down form, I can't find the corresponding element to locate it by element. As shown in the screenshot, the element that contains the content of the option is changing as I click on different options on the screen.

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl9XA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaIAJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3R03.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you have to use `JavaScript` for this.